# Is there a easy way to change the path in django?

Tags: python, django

I get the templates files, I divide them to `static` files and `templates` files.

[image]

As you know I can not correct open the html in browser now, because thier path all changed.

I can in the templates files to change every link or script and image path one by one, but its a trouble things, takes our away many time.

Is there a simple way to do that?

---

**EDIT**

I changed to this, but not works for me:

```
{% load static %}
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/default.min.css?t=227" />-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/default.min.css?t=227' %}" />
```

in the browser debugger, it become this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/default.min.css%3Ft%3D227">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to use the `{% static %}` tag in the templates, like this:

```
{% load static %}
...
<img src="{% static 'images/favicon.png' %}">
```

For more information, check [my detailed explanation](https://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/21/how-django-static-files-work-in-production/).